# AWS Glue maximum and transform rows

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I am trying to load data in one of the table created using AWS glue from source bucket S1.

Source bucket having 4 columns`( session_id, Date, type, action )` with below values. Purchase transaction lasted for 1 min and we get 2 records for the same. In some cases we dont get end records

```
session_id, Date, type, action
1, 01jan20 10:00, purchase, start
1, 01jan20 10:01, Purchase, End
1, 02jan20 11:01, bal, start 
1, 02jan20 11:05, bal, end 
2, 02jan20 11:10, bal, start
```

I have target table where I wanted to insert these records. It has below structure.

```
id, startdt, enddt, duration_spent_seconds, action
1 01jan20 10:00, 01jan20 10:01, 60, Purchase
1 01jan20 11:01, 01jan20 11:05, 240, bal
2 01jan20 11:10, , , Bal
```

I am trying AWS glue and would like store target table/result to S3.

Can someone please help me in details on how to achieve this please?

It would be really great for me to start

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to read and write csv files from s3 using either [dynamicFrames](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame-reader.html) or [boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html). Either way you likely want to use [apache spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/index.html) dataFrames to handle the transformation to your desired schema.

Boto3 will read the data in as a dataFrame directly, whereas you will need to transform the dynamicFrame into a dataFrame using `df = dynamicFrame.toDF()`.